# SOAP request from php to CRMOnline

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a simple PHP script with SOAP calls to my CRM Online.  I can create and retrieve records, but I'm having trouble with setting the customer of entities.  One of my SOAP calls is as such; it creates the record but doesn't set the customer.

```
        $liveIDManager = new LiveIDManager();

    $securityData = $liveIDManager->authenticateWithLiveID($organizationServiceURL, $liveIDUseranme, $liveIDPassword);

    if($securityData!=null && isset($securityData)){
        //echo ("\nKey Identifier:" . $securityData->getKeyIdentifier());
        //echo ("\nSecurity Token 1:" . $securityData->getSecurityToken0());
        //echo ("\nSecurity Token 2:" . $securityData->getSecurityToken1());
    }else{
        echo "Unable to authenticate LiveId.";
        return;
    }
    echo "\n";
            $domainname = substr($CRMURL,8,-1);
    $pos = strpos($domainname, "/");
    $domainname = substr($domainname,0,$pos);
    print_r($data);
    $contactRequest = EntityUtils::getCreateCRMSoapHeader($CRMURL, $securityData).
    <s:Body>
                <Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">
                <entity xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <b:Attributes xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
                        <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <c:key>firstname</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'.$data['Account']['name'].'</c:value>
                            <c:key>parentcustomerid</c:key>
                            <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'.$data['Account']['id'].'</c:value>
                        </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    </b:Attributes>
                    <b:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
                    <b:FormattedValues xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                    <b:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:Id>
                    <b:LogicalName>contact</b:LogicalName>
                    <b:RelatedEntities xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                </entity>
                </Create>
            </s:Body>
    $response =  LiveIDManager::GetSOAPResponse("/Organization.svc", $domainname, $CRMURL, $accountsRequest);
    echo $response;
    $createResult ="";
    if($response!=null && $response!=""){
        preg_match('/<CreateResult>(.*)<\/CreateResult>/', $response, $matches);

        $createResult =  $matches[1];
    }
```

Has anyone been through this and/or know what I'm missing?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the type of the value to EnitityReference among other things; the updated body of my SOAP is below.`<b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                                  <c:key>firstname</c:key>
                                  <c:value i:type="d:string" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'.$data['Account']['name'].'</c:value>
                              </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                              <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                                  <c:key>parentcustomerid</c:key>
                                  <c:value i:type="b:EntityReference">
                                      <b:Id>'.$data['Account']['category'].'</b:Id>
                                      <b:LogicalName>account</b:LogicalName>
                                      <b:Name i:nil="true" />
                                  </c:value>
                              </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>`

Sorry for formatting...